# Django CreateView throws NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am building a simple app and I am facing difficulties with creating an object using class based views. I have a model:

Models.py:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = ...
    model = ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('vehicle-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.PK})
```

Then in views.py:

```
class VehicleCreate(CreateView):
    model = Vehicle
    fields = ['make','model']
```

myapp urls.py

```
url(r'vehicle/add/$', VehicleCreate.as_view(), name='vehicle-add'),
```

All I've written above is only related to the CreateView. Everything is imported properly according to the needs of the CreateView cbv. When I visit mydomain.com/vehicle/add/ there is a form with all the fields of the model but when I hit Create button it throws an error NoReverseMatch.
I am writing from my phone and that's why its a bit difficult for me to post full .py files content.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: You have shown the `vehicle-add` url, To see why `reverse('vehicle-detail', ...)` is failing, we need to see the `vehicle-detail` url.

Comment: Hm, I don't actually have vehicle-detail url. But it has not been mentioned in the documentation. What should that url point to? Could you please give me more detailed explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the docs you are looking at. If you work through the [display views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) first, then move on to the [editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/), then maybe it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `get_absolute_url` method for your model.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('vehicle-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.PK})
```

For this to work, there needs to be a url pattern named `vehicle-detail` that accepts a primary key as a keyword argument.

You could create the view using [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

```
class VehicleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Vehicle
    ...
```

You'll have to create an appropriate template.

Then add the url pattern with something like:

```
url(r'vehicle/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', VehicleDetail.as_view(), name='vehicle-detail'),
```

Comment: That seems to be the thing I've been missing. I didn't know I need to have both CreateView and DetailView. So the reverse should redirect the user to the DetailView - am I right?

Comment: Django has generic views for creating (`CreateView`), reading/viewing (`DetailView`), updating (`UpdateView`),  and deleting (`DeleteView`). By default, your `CreateView` will redirect to the new object's url, but for this to work, you need to define `get_absolute_url`. Normally, it makes sense for `get_absolute_url` to use the detail view for that model.

Comment: I've figured it out. Thank you for your help.